# How can I access other scripts(Bash) and their functions into mine

Tags: bash

How can I access other scripts and their functions into mine

FOR Example:-

i have two Scripts S1 and S2

**S1.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
S="./SSSS"
W="./WWWW"
T="./TTTT"
```

and **S2.sh**
i would like to use the declared paths in S1 into S2

```
#!/bin/bash 

if[[ -f $S ]]; then
echo "Got to use the S from S1"
fi;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have `S2.sh` like this:

```
#!/bin/bash 
. ./S1.sh

if [[ -f $S ]]; then
   echo "Got to use the S from S1"
fi
```

That is basically calling `S1.sh` from `S2.sh` in the **same sub shell process**

Comment: looks like i need to wait till 10mints to do it-:(

Comment: does ../ before the filename does mean anything

Comment: `./` means execute from current directory and first dot `. ` means execute in the current sub shell.

Comment: does it works even if   the files are in different directories ../ workes as expected

Comment: If `S1.sh` is in some directory like `/home/tom/work` then you can have this line at the top: `. /home/tom/work/S1.sh`

Answer (score 0):

You can include S1.sh like this:

```
#!/bin/bash 
. ./S1.sh

if[[ -f $S ]]; then
echo "Got to use the S from S1"
fi;
```

Or

```
#!/bin/bash 
source S1.sh

if[[ -f $S ]]; then
echo "Got to use the S from S1"
fi;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should include the other file, e.g. in S2.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

. S1.sh
if[[ -f $S ]]; then
  echo "Got to use the S from S1"
fi
```

This assumes they're in the same path. If not, using relative paths and `$(dirname $0)` helps a lot.